# Generated sequence id (From DB Sequence) in Spring boot with JPA is shared by other server/Instance and causing unique constraint violated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

We are developing new API service for key modules in the application and using Spring boot and JPA 
Here we need your support as we facing one issue regarding sequence generated by JPA framework 
Generated sequence id is shared by other server/Instance in parallel  and causing unique constraint  violated

could you please provide any suggestion on this to find the root cause of this and below is the annotations we used at entity definition.

Used annotations are

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "POT_PO_HEADER_S1", sequenceName = "POT_PO_HEADER_S1", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "POT_PO_HEADER_S1")
@Column(name="POH_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
private Long pohId;
```

And Log is

```
 select
        pot_po_header_s1.nextval 
    from
        dual
2020-Feb-06 11:18:30.808 DEBUG [http-nio-8060-exec-1] o.h.i.e.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 14021954

 2020-Feb-06 11:18:32.019 DEBUG [http-nio-8060-exec-1] o.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        pot_po_header
        (dept_code, dist_center, po_number, pot_cust_id, source_id, source_table, create_user, modify_user, create_user_name, modify_user_name, poh_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-Feb-06 11:18:32.673 DEBUG [http-nio-8060-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TNT_OWNER.POT_PO_HEADER_PK) violated
```

Comment: `Generated sequence id is shared by other server/Instance` are you sure that all your apps use this sequence and the same `allocationSize = 1`. Do you have gaps in the sequence generated values?

Comment: Some info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972881/should-javax-persistence-sequencegenerator-allocationsize-be-consistent-with-i

Comment: all apps are separate instances but using same DB sequence and even though without gap  generated  sequence should not share to 2 operations

Comment: On is from Test automation scripts and running from tomcat and another is from local eclipse Spring boot inbuilt server and there may not maintain gap between generation time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you obtain your sequence id which got printed as below in your logs

`2020-Feb-06 11:18:30.808 DEBUG [http-nio-8060-exec-1] o.h.i.e.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 14021954`

You will get the sequence value once you save your entity like below

`Entityr e = epository.save(entity);`
then you can have your autogenerated value for `pohId` as
`e.getPohId`

Comment: That log statement is generated by HIbernate obtaining the next val for the insert.

Comment: Yes we are doing save with below statement    poHdrDB = headerRepository.save(poHdrDB);